# Mapbox GL JS performance with multiple layers

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am creating an app using `mapbox-gl-js` which has a lot of layers. The users have the option to show/hide these layers.

Performance wise, is it better (1) to create all layers at once and display/hide them when it's needed using opacity or visibility for example or should (2) I create/remove the layers every time I show/hide them?

If option 1 is the best, should I use opacity (paint property) or visibility (layout property) to control this show/hide behavior?